# Is there a way to make my a JavaScript file not to run in a html page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two html files(*index.html* and *project.html*), *index.html* contain or needs two javascript files(*main.js* and *index.js*).
The *main.js* contains the functions that both html files needs. And the *index.js* has the functons that only *index.html* needs.

So am saying **index.html-->(*main.js,index.js*) and project.html-->(*main.js)***.
The issue is that when I open the project.html the DOM elements that I called in *index.js* is throwing errors saying that the element is null.

The thing is that the DOM element that is causing the error is only created in *index.html* and not *project.html* but project is not supposed to call or know that function.

**index.html**

```
<script src="asset/javaScript/javaScript_for_index/main.js" defer type="module"></script>
<script src="asset/javaScript/javaScript_for_index/index.js" defer type="module"></script>
```

**project.html**

```
<script src="asset/javaScript/javaScript_for_index/main.js" defer type="module"></script>
```

This is where i get the error in the inspector. Note that the error comes from the *project.html* and it is caused by the *index.js*

I know that this is a bit confusing but this is the best i can explain it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Help others reproduce the problem", where it is noted, "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question."

Comment: And please put only relevant code, not ALL the code. if vars from lines 11 to 13 are not necessary to show, don't put them.

Comment: You've got `type="module"` on both scripts. Does one script `import` the other?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Note that *all* your `<script>` elements should appear in your markup before the closing `</body>` element.
2. On each page, *only* reference the `<script>`(s) that you need for that page

**Example:**

### `index.html`

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### `project.html`

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried that but it did't work, i only referenced the required script to the html pages. Is there a way to tell the script to not work on a certain page?

Comment: In the example above, as far as `project.html` is concerned, `index.js` doesn't exist. You don't need to tell it not to work: it literally doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you must have something in main.js that is referencing DOM parts that are in index.html. Stop referencing those, and you'll be okay. Note, that if I have a `DIV` in index.html with ID `foo` which project.html does not have, then you can use `document.querySelectorAll()` function to check if that element exists (can look at `length`, returned from that, as well as other options like `undefined`), and then react if it doesn't exist. That can help you delineate items from index.html versus project.html.

Comment: True the DOM element used in index.js is only found in index.html. Thats why i am looking for a way to stop project.html from knowing that index.js exist.

Comment: And if i stop referencing those DOM parts, i won't be able to use the id of the div in index.html

Answer (score 1):

Before we do anything start with clearing your cache. (Important)

If you are sure that you have done everything right,  just like @Rounin answer suggest,
Then run your code again,  inspect to make sure your error is coming from index.js and if it is,  then you are somehow injecting index.js into the page without knowing ,  (maybe somewhere at the middle of your body or something else),  you might have to do a more thorough debugging than just asking. And most probably you have not told us everything because you might not be aware of it.

Try searching for any occurrence of index.js on your project.html script. (Ctrl+F)

Now if all else fails and you have to move on fast,  then u can try this hack on your index.html and index.js script.

**Index.html**

```
    <script> var page = "index" </script>
```

Put this on line 1, before anything else, because I don't know what line might be caising your problem

Then on **index.js** wrap your codes with an if statement (i.e put if statements to check if the page = "index" to prevent unwanted codes from running on other pages

E.g:

```
    If (typeof page !== undefined && page == "index") {
         // allow code to execute
    }
```

This is a dirty hack,  but it might kept you going until you get a more experience engineer to debug your codes...

Comment: .I love this ideal am sure it will work. Thank you

Comment: I have checked my project.js code and there is no sign that index.js is in it. Thanks for your quick fix.

Comment: @etemire ewoma,  i believe you wanted to type "I have checked my project.html" not project.js...

Answer (score 1):

Example:

index.html needs main.js and index.js
project.html needs A CERTAIN function in main.js ONLY

so main.js

```
function functionsThatIndexNeeds() {
alert('Im in index.html!!!');
}

function functionsThatProjectNeeds() {

alert('IM IN PROJECTS~~~');
}
```

index.html

```
<script>functionsThatIndexNeeds()</script>
```

projects.html

```
<script>functionsThatProjectNeeds</script>
```

The point is to call ONLY the functions that each HTML files need.

Tell me if this works on you!:)

Comment: This is really cool, am sure it will work. I will try it now!

Comment: Happy to help:)